# Select child elements during web scraping with pupeeteer and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a page using nodejs and puppeeter, here is an exemple of the page content i want to scrape :

```
<article>
   <h3 class="item-title">Item 1 </h3>
   <img src="" alt="" alt="picture for this item" class="item-image">
   <a href="link-to-the-page" class="view-more">View more</a>
</article>

<article>
  <h3 class="item-title">Item 2 </h3>
  <img src="path-to-the-image" alt="" alt="picture for this item" class="item-image">
  <a href="link-to-the-page" class="view-more">View more</a>
</article>

<article>
  <h3 class="item-title">Item 2 </h3>
  <img src="path-to-the-image" alt="" alt="picture for this item" class="item-image">
  <a href="link-to-the-page" class="view-more">View more</a>
</article>
```

As you can see there are many items wrapped in `article` tag, i want to get the list of articles and their corresponding **title, image link and fullpage link**. here is the code i am using :

```
var puppeeteer = require('puppeeteer');
var browser = await puppeeteer.launch();
var page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('link-to-the=page');
var articles = await page.evaluate(()=>{
     var articles = new Array();
     document.querySelectorAll("article").forEach(elt=> { articles.push(elt); });
     return articles;
});

//Here, for each elements in articles array, i try to get : the image link, the title, and the fullpage link.

var result = new Array();
articles.forEach(elt=>{
    var article = {};
    var item_title= elt.getElementsByClassName("item-title")[0];
    var fullpage_link = elt.getElementsByClassName("view-more")[0];
    var image_path = elt.getElementsByClassName("item-image")[0];

    article.title = item_title;
    article.link = fullpage_link;
    article.image = image_path;
    result.push(article);
});

return result;
```

But when i run this code, here is the error i get :

**(node:3960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: elt.getElementsByClassName is not a function**

The other error is that articles array contains this :

```
[ {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ]
```

After code execution.

Can someone help please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the html in your question (and fixing a couple of errors in it), something like this (using xpath) should work:

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<article>
   <h3 class="item-title">Item 1 </h3>
   <img src="path-to-the-image_1"  alt="picture for this item" class="item-image">
   <a href="link-to-the-page_1" class="view-more">View more</a>
</article>

<article>
  <h3 class="item-title">Item 2 </h3>
  <img src="path-to-the-image_2"  alt="picture for this item" class="item-image">
  <a href="link-to-the-page_2" class="view-more">View more</a>
</article>

<article>
  <h3 class="item-title">Item 3 </h3>
  <img src="path-to-the-image_3"  alt="picture for this item" class="item-image">
  <a href="link-to-the-page_3" class="view-more">View more</a>
</article>`
    ,'text/xml');

var xpath = require('xpath');
const articles = xpath.select("//article", doc);
var result = new Array();
articles.forEach(function(item){
  var article = {};
  title = xpath.select('./h3/text()',item);
  fpl = xpath.select('./a/@href',item);
  isrc = xpath.select('./img/@src',item);

  article.title = title[0].nodeValue;
  article.link = fpl[0].nodeValue;
  article.image = isrc[0].nodeValue;

  result.push(article);
});
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
[ { title: 'Item 1 ',
    link: 'link-to-the-page_1',
    image: 'path-to-the-image_1' },

  { title: 'Item 2 ',
    link: 'link-to-the-page_2',
    image: 'path-to-the-image_2' },

  { title: 'Item 3 ',
    link: 'link-to-the-page_3',
    image: 'path-to-the-image_3' } ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @THEHOLYSPIRIT - You are welcome, but does it work?